# Rotate an image around center using batch draw

Tags: libgdx

```
float rotateBy= (float) (bird.clockWise?(-1):(1)*1/deltaTime*(Math.PI/180))/30;


float rotatedX = (float) (Math.cos(rotateBy) * (transform.position.x - bird.center.x) - Math.sin(rotateBy) * (transform.position.y-bird.center.y) + bird.center.x);
float rotatedY = (float) (Math.sin(rotateBy) * (transform.position.x - bird.center.x) + Math.cos(rotateBy) * (transform.position.y - bird.center.y) + bird.center.y);
transform.position.set(rotatedX, rotatedY);
Gdx.app.log("RenderingSystem","Rotate:"+rotatedX);
batch.draw(texture.textRegion,transform.position.x,transform.position.y,bird.center.x,bird.center.y
        ,texture.textRegion.getRegionWidth(),texture.textRegion.getRegionHeight(),1,1,  MathUtils.radiansToDegrees * rotateBy);
```

I wrote above code for rotating texture around any point.My problem is that While texture is rotating around center point ,  texture is not rotating by the center point.

Comment: What do you mean? Explain rotating by.

Comment: I want this situation -> http://i.stack.imgur.com/KLf1W.png
but my code , cube's edge does not rotate according to center.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Sprite. And change center according to the point you want to rotate around.

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Spritebatch,-Textureregions,-and-Sprites

https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.html

What you are looking for is `setCenter` function. Set the center to the center of the circle in the image (the image in the comments). Then use `sprite.draw(...)` function.

Sprites are very useful and saves you time. You might need to change some code and/or erase some, though.

Comment: transform.position.set(rotatedX, rotatedY);
                sprite.setOrigin(bird.center.x,bird.center.y);
                sprite.setPosition(transform.position.x,transform.position.y);

                sprite.draw(batch);

I did what you say . But it does not work.

Comment: @SemihY use **rotate** function. I didn't know I had to say to use **rotate** function. I thought you could figure it out. My mistake, sorry.

Comment: I did it before you said. But It does not rotate. :( Could you give code example for rotating